# How do I map over parameters?

Tags: haskell, generics

Given the type `X = X Int Int`, I want to define a function `toX :: [String] -> X` which constructs an `X` during runtime with generics.

This is easy when I just write it down like this:

```
toX :: [String] -> X
toX (x:[y]) = to (M1 (M1 (M1 (K1 $ read x) :*: (M1 (K1 $ read y)))))
```

But I don't know how to do it recursive (in case we have a lot more than two parameters). My first try was something like this:

```
toX xs = to (M1 (M1 (toX' xs)))

toX' (x:[]) = M1 (K1 x)
toX' (x:xs) = M1 (K1 x) :*: (toX' xs)
```

which (of course) fails with a type error. Looking at the type of `(:*:)` confuses me even more: `(:*:) :: f p -> g p -> (:*:) f g p`. I have absolutely no idea what this type is supposed to mean and how to proceed from here.
Any hints?

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --resolver lts-8.4 runghc-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import GHC.Generics
data X = X Int Int deriving (Generic, Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ toXeasy ["2","4"]
--    print $ toX ["2","4"]

toXeasy :: [String] -> X
toXeasy (x:[y]) = to (M1 (M1 (M1 (K1 $ read x) :*: (M1 (K1 $ read y)))))

--toX :: [String] -> X
--toX xs = to (M1 (M1 (toX' xs)))

--toX' (x:[]) = M1 (K1 x)
--toX' (x:xs) = M1 (K1 x) :*: (toX' xs)
```

Comment: Here is something you may want to ponder - what should the type of `toX'` be? Does it even _have_ a type?

Comment: On needs to have more type-level information to do this. An `HList` just might be enough.

Comment: It's not clear why you want to do this using Generics. Defining functions with Generic should involve defining type classes. I would guess you have multiple types, which are simple records of values, is that right? Could you clarify your problem by showing various examples of types you want to handle and simple unit tests?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Currently I am just playing around to see what's possible with generics. I'm trying to reimplement something like cassava/csv-conduit (parse CSV into a datatype) but only a minimal example for learning purposes. I came up with the code in my question and thought it would be more elegant with a recursive definition.

Comment: @Alec The type of `toX'` is a mystery to me because the type of `:*:` is a mystery to me :) Not sure how a `HList` would help here, will think about it these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This defines a function `readFields :: [String] -> Maybe X` for any `Generic` data type  `X` which has only one constructor (with at least one field).

`readFields` is defined using a generic version `gReadFields` which works with generic representations (i.e., types constructed using type constructors that appear in `GHC.Generics`: `M1`, `(:*:)`, `K1`...).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module A where

import GHC.Generics
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Text.Read

data X = X Int Int deriving (Generic, Show)

main = print (readFields ["14", "41"] :: Maybe X)

readFields :: (Generic a, GReadableFields (Rep a)) => [String] -> Maybe a
readFields xs = fmap to (evalStateT gReadFields xs)

class GReadableFields f where
  gReadFields :: StateT [String] Maybe (f p)

instance GReadableFields f => GReadableFields (M1 i c f) where
  gReadFields = fmap M1 gReadFields

-- When your type is a large product, you cannot assume that
-- the generic product structure formed using `(:*:)` is list-
-- like (field1 :*: (field2 :*: (field3 ...)), so it is not
-- clear how to split the input list of strings to read each
-- component. For that reason we use `State`. Another possible way
-- is to compute the number of fields of the two operands `f` and `g`.
instance (GReadableFields f, GReadableFields g) => GReadableFields (f :*: g) where
  gReadFields = do
    f <- gReadFields
    g <- gReadFields
    return (f :*: g)

instance Read c => GReadableFields (K1 i c) where
  gReadFields = StateT $ \(x : xs) -> do
    c <- readMaybe x
    return (K1 c, xs)
```

Just for fun, here is a way of achieving a similar results which does not use generics. The user has to provide a constructor (or a function), and a type class takes care of filling all its arguments with values read from the list of strings.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, TypeFamilies #-}

module A where

data X = X Int Int deriving Show

main = print (readFields X ["14", "41"])

type family Result a where
  Result (a -> b) = Result b
  Result a = a

class ReadableFields a where
  readFields :: a -> [String] -> Maybe (Result a)

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (ReadableFields b, Read a) => ReadableFields (a -> b) where
  readFields f (x : xs) = do
    a <- readMaybe x
    readFields (f a) xs
  readFields _ _ = Nothing

instance (Result a ~ a) => ReadableFields a where
  readFields a _ = Just a
```

---

### EDIT

That use of `Generic` is straightforward enough that the underlying pattern is packaged in [one-liner](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/one-liner).

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Generics.OneLiner
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Text.Read
```

Define an action to read a single field. It is important that there is an instance `Applicative (StateT [String] Maybe)` so that it can be composed.

```
-- Takes a string from the state and reads it out.
readM :: Read a => StateT [String] Maybe a
readM = StateT readM'
  where 
    readM' (x : xs) | Just a <- readMaybe x = Just (a, xs)
    readM' _ = Nothing
```

This is now a one-liner, using `createA` from the one-liner library.

```
readFields xs = evalStateT (createA (For :: For Read) readM) xs

main = print (readFields ["14", "42"] :: Maybe (Int, Int))
```

Comment: All these `read` partial functions! I would expect something more like `gReadFields :: MaybeT (State [String]) (f p)`.

Comment: Okay, I hope this looks better now!

Comment: Thanks for the version without generics as well, very interesting!

Comment: You might want to take a look at my latest paragraph about `one-liner`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [generics-sop](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts, TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module ReadFields where

import Data.Maybe
import Generics.SOP
import Generics.SOP.TH

readFields ::
  (Generic a, Code a ~ '[ xs ], All Read xs) => [String] -> Maybe a
readFields xs =
  to . SOP . Z . hcmap (Proxy @Read) (I . read . unK) <$> fromList xs

data X = X Int Int
  deriving Show

deriveGeneric ''X
```

Testing:

```
GHCi> readFields @X ["3", "4"]
Just (X 3 4)
GHCi> readFields @X ["3"]
Nothing
```